# itunes connect sales reports won't go further than October 30th

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to view the Sales and Trends for my apps in iTunes Connect. I am only able to see sales up until 30th October, when I try to change the dates to include all days up to 5th November it does nothing.

It's quite possible that I had no sales in the time period 30th October - 4th November, but yesterday I had three new apps approved and released, I know that some of my friends have downloaded them so there should be some data to show.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I've emailed Apple but their reply can take 3 days apparently, and I'm anxious to get up to date figures for my new app.

**Update**

It magically seems to work for me today. And it seems that I had some sales in the period 30th October - 5th November, so the issue can't be due to no sales.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple support, not programming. You might try to give them a ring if possible.

Comment: May be off-topic but I'm reassured I'm not the only one experiencing the same problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I cleared out my browser history and cache and it is now working. If that doesn't work for you, try another browser. I usually use Chrome. Before clearing out Chrome's cache/history, I decided to try Safari. No luck. Then I tried Firefox and it worked there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, clearing the cache didn't work on Chrome though. I tried with Internet Explorer and got "An unexpected error occurred". I'll download Firefox and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like there is no sales data for the days after October 31; iTunes Connect does not allow me to display any date in November. I contacted support and will share the results later on.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I use iTunes Connect app from Apple https://itunes.apple.com/app/itunes-connect/id376771144?mt=8 - it works perfectly fine (while I see the same outdated results in browser)

Comment: iTunes Connect App doesn't give the level of detail required, if you want to know what app/inApp was purchased. It seems to high-level for me.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't 'fix' the problem, but if you create a new user within your account, it appears to  allow you to query to the current date. (Nov 5th). Time will tell if this reduces back to Oct 30th.  HTH